# How to search for an ampersand in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, ampersand

In Elasticsearch, how to search for a value with an ampersand? Tried:

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q=name:"procter \u0026 gamble"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways but one way would be to declare your string as `not_analyzed` in your mapping (see below) and then search for the exact value that has been indexed.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Now we index a sample document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests/test/1 -d '{"name":"procter & gamble"}'
```

And finally, your search query will return the document you expect:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tests/test/_search?q=name.raw:"procter %26 gamble"
```

**UPDATE** Here is another more involved way using an [`nGram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) which will index all the possible tokens of length 2 to 20 (arbitrary choice) of your names.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can search for the exact name like before

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tests/test/_search?q=name:"procter %26 gamble"
```

Or simply by some token present in your name

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tests/test/_search?q=name:procter
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tests/test/_search?q=name:"procter %26"
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tests/test/_search?q=name:gamble
```

Comment: I assume this works; however, I would like to be able to find the document per partial name, like "procter", too, so I need this field to be analysed. To avoid "if not found in name_analyzed, search in name_raw" logic, could you share other ways you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I exactly have nGram, and while full name query (q=name:"procter %26 gamble"), as well as partial without ampersand (q=name:procter) work, problem is, that partial with ampersand (GET /tests/test/_search?q=name:"procter %26") doesn't.

Comment: I've updated the mapping and added a `keyword` `search_analyzer` instead. That does the trick. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I used a little bit different approach.
Create a custom pattern analyzer with special chars (I used &'-@).

The original pattern analyzer in ES is "\W+"

As from ES documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

> The pattern analyzer uses a regular expression to split the text into terms. The regular expression should match the token separators not the tokens themselves. The regular expression defaults to \W+ (or all non-word characters).

So to add the special chars I wanted I had to invert the logic of this regex. This is my custom analyzer.

```
    "special_chars_analyzer": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "pattern": "[^\\w&'-@]+",
      "lowercase": true
    }
```